# How to have a fixed size not null varchar with OrmLite?

Tags: c#, sql, varchar, ormlite-servicestack, notnull

When declaring a `String` property in a Poco class, OrmLite will generate a `varchar(8000) NULL` column for it in the database. for e.g. I have the following class and the generated table for it:

[image]

[image]

I am wondering how can I specify the length for the field. It does not make sense to have 8000 characters for a FirstName for e.g. Also how can I force `NOT NULL`? The `UserName` and the `Password` columns should always have values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to look into using annotations:  `Required` and `StringLength`:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
```

So something like:

```
public class Users {
   ...
   [Required]
   [StringLength(50)]
   public String UserName { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I think that should do it.

Good luck.